# How to add items to the Rdlc report dynamically?

Tags: c#, json, rdlc

I have a service that returns a json concatinated string. I want that binded to the rdlc reportviewer to generate report.

In that concatinated string, I have 5 strings that will compose of dynamic data which we cannot estimate how many records it will contain coming from 5 different tables.

These 5 should be binded to 5 tables on report. The last string is composed of constant values that have to be binded to the table or textboxes as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to dynamically add the items to RDLC report. You can create data set from the concatinated string and set that dataset as datasource for RDLC report. In RDLC report you can add 5 different tables or matrix to show up these data.

You said, for fifth table you need to show it in textbox. It is not possible to show in text box. you have to use table or matrix for that.

Or else, RDLC report is just a XML structure. Your need to create your own RDLC report based on the input data dynamically. You can find RDLC specification here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd297486%28SQL.100%29.aspx